# Highcharts Angular - How to set chart width and height with percentages?

Tags: html, angular, highcharts, modal-dialog, size

I'm trying to set chart width and height according to the space around it. The chart is currently in a modal and I would like it to occupy the entire space. In order to do that I would need the width and height to be set with percentages but I'm not able to do that. The chart size seems to be set to a default value that can't be changed unless I do it in the options of the chart like this:

```
chartOptions: Options = {
    title: {
      text: 'CDF of the most frequent update frequency',
      style: {
        color: 'whitesmoke'
      }
    },
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      backgroundColor: {
            linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1 },
            stops: [
                [0, '#2a2a2b'],
                [1, '#3e3e40']
            ]
        },
      borderColor: 'black',
      borderWidth: 2,
      width: 1000,
      height: 500
    },
```

This allows me to only set the size with pixels and that's not what I need.
This is how the html page is set up:

```
<h4 mat-dialog-title>
        <mat-toolbar class="task-header">
            <span class="titolo">Most Frequent Update Frequency CDF</span>
            <button mat-icon-button mat-dialog-close class="icona">
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>close</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-toolbar>
</h4>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"></highcharts-chart>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove both `width` and `height` from highchart's `chart` config object. They both default to `null` and here's the behavior (taken from documentation):

- **height:** By default (when `null`) the height is calculated from the offset height of the containing element, or 400 pixels if the containing element's height is `0`.
- **width:**  By default (when `null`) the width is calculated from the offset width of the containing element.

The only thing left to do is to set explicit `height` and `width` on the containing `<mat-dialog-content>`. Here's why they need to be explicit:

- by default, the MatDialog component is trying to render as small as possible, but enough to fit the content.
- Highcharts, on the other hand, is trying to grow into the available space.

So we have a parent trying to shrink down on the child and a child trying to grow into the parent.
Meaning: *you need to provide **explicit sizes** to MatDialog,* or the parent will shrink on the child and the child won't have space to grow in (actually, there is a min-width on the dialog and the chart also defaults the height to `400px` when it detects a `0` height - to counter the shrinking parents).

Probably the most convenient way to set explicit sizes on the dialog is by placing a custom class on this particular MatDialog instance, using `panelClass` option in the second param of `.open()`. e.g:

```ts
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(HighchartsDialogComponent, {
  panelClass: 'highcharts-modal'
});
```

Now you could use CSS to set the explicit size of the modal: e.g:

```css
.cdk-overlay-pane.highcharts-modal {
   /*
    use any valid CSS explicit sizing: %, px, em, vw,...
    don't use `auto` (not explicit - will result into `0`)
    */
   width: 80vw;
   height: 80vh;
}
```

Side note: by default, `.cdk-overlay-pane` injects some inline styles, among which a `max-width: 80vw;`. If you want your chart to be wider than that, you'll have to override it using `!important` from CSS.

Another side note: MatDialog provides options to set `height` and `width` via config (where we specified `panelClass`). If set, they are passed as inline styles to the same panel element.

I prefer my CSS in stylesheets, not in config options, as it comes with the added benefit of allowing `@media` queries. But if you prefer the config, it works as well.

Comment: The modal's width and height were already set to similar values, I now set explicit height and width to the '<mat-dialog-content>' via CSS but the chart is still set to the default values of height and width.

Comment: I tried to set the modal's size your way but it seems the values are not getting recognised because no matter what I try to set the modal's size stay the same. I set the size like this:
`this.dialog.open(ModalMostFrequentUpdateComponent, {
      width: '100%',
      height: '640px'
    });`

Comment: @Maurizio, the reason behind that behavior is not present in you've shown so far, because [it should work](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8tjsj?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.ts). You might notice I'm also using `maxWidth: '100%'` there, to override the default of `80vw`, which I already specified in the answer. Without it, even if you do specify `width: '100%'`, it won't go above `80vw`. I can't help you further unless you create a [mcve] actually reproducing what you're describing, so I could figure out the cause.

Comment: Here's my project https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-lnx6fq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fhome%2Fmodal-most-frequent-update%2Fmodal-most-frequent-update.component.ts, I don't know why stackblitz is giving errors. Sorry, I didn't mean to be disrespectful

Comment: @Maurizio, have you also updated the stackblits's `package.json` to be the same as your local? They need to at least use the same version of angular.

Comment: Yes they are exactly the same

Comment: I believe the error has to do with the fact you and blitzstack have a different node version. I really don't know how I could help you here. The problem is around blitz not being able to find the schema in `"./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json"` (see angular.json) but I'm really not sure what the proper fix for that is. Bottom line, until you find a way for me to be able to inspect your issue, I can't really help.